# Config Nanoc in Docker Error facing "Nanoc::Core::ConfigLoader::NoConfigFileFoundError: No configuration file found"

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, dockerfile, nanoc

I try to create nanoc Markdown Documentation page deployment using docker.
Docker container was created successfully.
While running the container i am getting the nanoc configuration error and container stopped.

I have mentioned the steps followed for implementation.

**Followed Steps**
**Step 1**
**Docker file**

```
FROM ruby:latest

# Create app directory

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY Gemfile .

# Copy the files
COPY . ./docs

RUN bundler install
RUN apt update

# Start the development/staging server
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["bundler","exec","nanoc","view" ]
```

**Step 2**

```
docker build -t nanoc:latest .
```

**Step 3**

```
docker run -p 0.0.0.0:3000:3000 --name nanoc-latest -t -d nanoc:latest
```

**Docker Logs container ID**

[image]

Comment: We need to change the Docker file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Docker file update:

```
FROM ruby:2.3
RUN mkdir -p /user/src/app
COPY . /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app/docs

RUN bundle install
RUN bundle exec nanoc
EXPOSE 3000
CMD bundle exec nanoc view
```

This configuration will sole the above error.

Comment: https://gitlab.com/aathithanambi/nanoc-sample-file/-/tree/master project working Example.